# Python: Plot residuals on a fitted model

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the lines (residuals; cyan lines) between data points and the estimated model. Currently I'm doing so by iterating over all data points in my income `pandas.DataFrame` and adding vertical lines. `x`, `y` are the points' coordinates and `predicted` are the predictions (here the blue line).

```
plt.scatter(income["Education"], income["Income"], c='red')
plt.ylim(0,100)

for indx, (x, y, _, _, predicted) in income.iterrows():
    plt.axvline(x, y/100, predicted/100) # /100 because it needs floats [0,1]
```

Is there a more efficient way? This doesn't seem like a good approach for more than a few rows.

[image]

Comment: [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) only takes scalars, but [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) accepts also 1D arrays. Then you can also directly plot your values and don't need the transformation (0, 1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all note that [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) here only works by coincidence. In general the `y` values taken by `axvline` are in coordinates relative to the axes, not in data coordinates.

In contrast, [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html) uses data coordinates and also has the advantage to accept arrays of values. It will then create a `LineCollection`, which is more efficient than individual lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1.2,1.2,20)
y = np.sin(x)
dy = (np.random.rand(20)-0.5)*0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.scatter(x,y+dy)

ax.vlines(x,y,y+dy)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly coincidence, since I intentionally set `plt.ylim(0,100)` and then divided by 100, but I get your point, this is a patch not a proper approach. Anyhow, thanks for your input!