# Julia: Plot residuals on a fitted model

Tags: statistics, julia

I'm trying to figure out how to make a residual plot like this to show the deviation from the predicted results:
[image]

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51220918/python-plot-residuals-on-a-fitted-model) which seems to answer it in Python, but I can't find in the Plots.jl docs or just google how to do that in Julia.

Note: data is not an issue here, I can handle that, it's just the literal plotting API I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to complement aramirezreyes's answer with [this Julia discourse answer](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/vlines-ymin-ymax/54671/2), you might want to avoid the loop if you have many points (because calling `plot!` can be expensive and you might want to avoid many series). In this case, you can insert `NaN`s between the coordinates of each bar. For example,

```
julia> x2 = repeat(points_x, inner=3) ;

julia> y2 = reduce(vcat, [y, yhat, NaN] for (y, yhat) in zip(points_x, points_y)) ;

julia> p1 = plot(points_x, points_x) #Plotting the fit

julia> plot!(x2, y2, lab="")

julia> scatter!(p1, points_x, points_y, c=2) #Plotting the points
```

will give you

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That one-liner for y2 is pretty neat and tidy!

Answer (score 3):

What are you struggling with in the API?
What have you tried so far?

```
julia> points_y = [x for x in 1:10] .+ rand(10)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
  1.1165819028282722
  2.986599717814377
  3.5743557742882377
  4.835499304548991
  5.106506715905332
  6.483859149461656
  7.041461273394912
  8.22314808617758
  9.128892867863867
 10.891435553032899

julia> points_x = 1:10
1:10

julia> p1 = plot(points_x,points_x) #Plotting the fit

julia> scatter!(p1,points_x,points_y) #Plotting the points

julia> for i in 1:length(points_x)
           plot!(p1,[points_x[i], points_x[i]],[points_x[i],points_y[i]], color=:black, legend=false)
       end

julia> p1
```

Produces this:

[image: Output]

In the for loop, which I think is what interests you, I am just drawing lines between the point in the fit (x,f(x)) and the scattered point (x, y), so the syntax becomes plot!(p,[x,x],[f(x),y]). A little difficult to get deeper as you are not specifying in what part of the process are you struggling.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I was mostly wondering if there was a more native way to draw the stick plot lines connecting the residual values to the regression line without having to "manually" do it in a for-loop. If not, this seems like about the best way to do it.

Comment: don't fear for loops. They are your friend.

Comment: Nice. You could omit the comprehension and just do `points_y = points_x .+ rand(10)`.